# PySpark - ALS Recommendation too too slow

Tags: apache-spark, time, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to build ALS recommender system for Amazon data set which has aroound 140 million reviews. I'm building ALS recommendation system using pyspark.

The runtime for ALS train is super slow. Initially I started with the whole records and it ran for around 8hours after which I terminated it. Inorder to test, I ran for 10 records and it took around 35mins. I couldn't understand why it takes so much time. I have searched for the past 2 days in vain.

I'm using Google Cloud service. Config - 16CPUs, 104 memory, 100GB SSD harddisk.

I'm configuring spark context as

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf()
conf = (conf.setMaster('local[*]')
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '50G')
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '30G')
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '15G')
       )
sc   = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

I'm new to Spark and I'm wondering maybe I'm making mistake in setting up spark configuration and by mistake am I running as standalone job instead of clusters?

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at your driver's web UI? How many executors? How much memory they're each having? And what are your transformations?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele It is `local`.

Comment: How do I check the web UI?

Comment: localhost:4040 is your driver's web ui.

Comment: Since I'm accessing through ip. I tried http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:4040.. But couldn't reach the webpage

Comment: That could be because of firewalls. Otherwise, you may need to update your driver's bind/local IP address. Check this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking for configuration properties